# How can Adobe Acrobat Reader be installed in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, adobe-reader

It's getting silly that there doesn't seem to be alternative that can deal with JavaScript-driven vector animations in PDFs, but c'est la vie: how can Adobe Acrobat Reader be installed in Ubuntu 15.04?

Roughly what I did previously was something like the following:

```
# Get AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb.
sudo apt-get -y install gdebi
sudo gdebi --non-interactive AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns* libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

This approach doesn't seem to work anymore. I see errors like the following for dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

and like the following for installation of the package itself:

```
This package is uninstallable
Cannot install 'libgtk2.0-0:i386'
```

Could anyone suggest an approach for installation?

Answer (score 5):

Try out an old Canonical partner repo for Raring Ringtail. Works fine on 15.04 for Adobe Reader installation.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns* libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Adobe Reader 9 shouldn't be used though. It will not get any security updates anymore and might not be safe. Of course it's fine, if your pdf source is reliable. It's still recommended to find an alternative.

Comment: I recently did this method from another post and found it easiest.  Don't forget to remove the archive though.

Answer (score 5):

Even if discontinued, you can still download it from Adobe:

```
wget -P /tmp/ http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
wget http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.bin
chmod +x ./AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.bin
sudo ./AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.bin
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! .deb files are built for Debian variants like Ubuntu, so could you explain why you use the .bin instead?