# How can Adobe Acrobat Reader be seriously installed in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, adobe-acrobat

None of methods that are suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620309/how-can-adobe-acrobat-reader-be-installed-in-ubuntu-15-04) work on my laptop. 
Do you know another way to install it?

Comment: Great; thanks for editing the text; I am a writer and have some works published but in Italian and Spanish only, not in English.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/89129/438174).

If you get any dependencies issue, try opening the .deb file in **Ubuntu Software Center**. It will download the required files and repair the installation.

EDIT: Check the change in link.

Answer (score 0):

Test Okular instead of Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Okular can:

Commenting on PDF documents, highlighting and drawing lines, geometric shapes, adding textboxes, and stamps, forms,...

You can install it from Ubuntu Software Center.